# Composite-id on hibernate and spring

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I was trying to implement a composite primary key on Hibernate and Spring.

Catalog has a catalogId, Book has a composite id (catalogId and bookId) so I've implemented BookId class using @Embeddable annotation.

Catalog.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    private Integer id;
    private Timestamp date;


    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public Catalog() {
    }


    public Catalog(Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "date")
    public Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
        this.date = date;
    }



    @OneToMany(mappedBy="catalog")
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<Book> lineasCatalog) {
        this.books = books;
    }

}
```

BookId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class BookId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "id_catalog")
    private Integer idCatalog;

    @Column(name = "id_book")
    private Integer idBook;

    public BookId() {
    }

    public BookId(Integer idCatalog, Integer idBook) {
        this.idCatalog = idCatalog;
        this.idBook = idBook;
    }

    public Integer getIdCatalog() {
        return idCatalog;
    }

    public void setIdCatalog(Integer idCatalog) {
        this.idCatalog = idCatalog;
    }

    public Integer getIdBook() {
        return idBook;
    }

    public void setIdBook(Integer idBook) {
        this.idBook = idBook;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getIdCatalog(), getIdBook());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof BookId)) return false;
        BookId that = (BookId) o;
        return Objects.equals(getIdCatalog(), that.getIdCatalog()) &&
                Objects.equals(getIdBook(), that.getIdBook());

    }

}
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {


    private BookId idBook;

    private Integer pages;
    private String title;

    private Catalog catalog;

    public Book(Integer pages, Catalog catalog) {
        this.pages = pages;
        this.catalog = catalog;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public BookId getIdBook() {
        return idBook;
    }

    public void setIdBook(BookId idBook) {
        this.idBook = idBook;
    }


    @Column(name = "pages")
    public Integer getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(Integer pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Column(name = "title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_catalog")
    public Catalog getCatalog() {
        return catalog;
    }

    public void setCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
        this.catalog = catalog;
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
    public void addCatalog(Catalog catalog, List<Book> books) {
        catalogDao.insert(catalog);

        for(int i=0; i<books.size(); i++) {
            BookId bid = new BookId();
            bid.setIdBook(i+1);
            bid.setIdCatalog(catalog.getId());          

            Book b = new Book();
            b.setIdBook(bid);

            b.setPages(books.get(i).getPages());
            b.setTitle(books.get(i).getTitle());
            b.setCatalog(catalog);

            catalog.getBooks().add(b);

            bookDao.insert(b);
        }
    }
```

I get the next error:

```
oct 06, 2018 9:27:59 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.myapp.BookId
oct 06, 2018 9:27:59 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.myapp.BookId
```

I have implemented equals() and hashCode() override methods so I can't understand why is the problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that Hibernate warning is triggered by other problems in the mappings. One problem I see in yours is the `Book.catalog` mapping. You should use a "derived identity" and add a `@MapsId` annotation:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idCatalog") // maps idCatalog attribute of embedded id
    @JoinColumn(name="id_catalog")
    public Catalog getCatalog() {
        return catalog;
    }
```

Comment: I added @MapsId("idCatalog") but I get the next error:
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.myapp.Book.catalog]

Comment: That could be because you did not set the book's catalog (i.e. `book.setCatalog(catalog)`) before writing the book to the database?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post to add the content of the method "addCatalog" on the service. I found a few problems but now I get and infinite loop. The code generate ids but it never inserts the books on the db

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure I understand how you get an infinite loop and not have the books inserted; since you call `bookDao.insert(b);` inside the loop. Where is the infinite loop? Also, it does not smell quite right that you pass in a list of books to your method and build a copy of each book in it to add to the catalog and insert to the database....

Comment: I found that the infinite loop is in the line: catalog.getBooks().add(b);
And if I comment that line, it doesn't insert on the db

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had to delete the catalog.getBooks().add(b) and fix a error with the relationship between books and catalog but now it works!